# How to get the CloudFront distribution ARN in a CloudFormation stack for WebACLAssociation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

I've setup a CloudFront distribution in CloudFormation and I'm building an AWS WAF ACL to act as a firewall for it. To associate the ACL to the CloudFront distribution, I've added a `AWS::WAFv2::WebACLAssociation` entry which requires the ARN of the CloudFront distribution for the `ResourceArn` entry. However, I can't seem to find out how to get the CloudFront distribution ARN from the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudfront-distribution.html). I thought I could use `!Ref` however it used the CloudFront ID as per the documentation instead of the ARN.

**How do I reference the CloudFront distribution ARN from the WebACLAssociation entry?**

Example below (other resources omitted for brevity):

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: CloudFront

Parameters:
  # ...
  CloudFront:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    DependsOn:
      - IssuedCertificate
      - S3Bucket
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !Sub
              - ${S3Bucket}.${S3WebEndpoint}
              - {
                  S3Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket,
                  S3WebEndpoint:
                    !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", websiteendpoint],
                }
            Id: S3origin
            CustomOriginConfig:
              OriginProtocolPolicy: http-only
        Enabled: "true"
        Comment: !Sub Distribution for ${DomainName}
        HttpVersion: http2
        Aliases:
          - !Ref DomainName
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
          TargetOriginId: S3origin
          Compress: True
          DefaultTTL: 604800
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: "false"
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        PriceClass: PriceClass_100
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !Ref Certificate
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
  # ...
  AWSWAF:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACL
    Properties:
      Name: allowlist
      Description: Allowlist
      Scope: CLOUDFRONT
      DefaultAction:
        Block: {}
      Rules:
        - Name: ipset-rule
          Priority: 0
          Action:
            Allow: {}
          Statement:
            IPSetReferenceStatement:
              Arn: # <ARN>
          VisibilityConfig:
            SampledRequestsEnabled: true
            CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
            MetricName: ipset-metrics
      VisibilityConfig:
        SampledRequestsEnabled: true
        CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        MetricName: allowlist-metrics

  AWSWAFAssociation:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACLAssociation
    Properties:
      ResourceArn: !Ref CloudFront
      WebACLArn: !Ref AWSWAF
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I had been approaching the problem wrong all along. Diving into the docs, I found that AWS details how to deploy an ACL for a CloudFront distribution [here under the ResouceArn entry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webaclassociation.html).

To fix this issue, all I had to do was add the following to the CloudFront distribution `DistributionConfig` and remove the `WebACLAssociation` entry:

```
WebACLId: !GetAtt AWSWAF.Arn
```

So the final CloudFront entry looked like this:

```
  CloudFront:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    DependsOn:
      - IssuedCertificate
      - S3Bucket
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !Sub
              - ${S3Bucket}.${S3WebEndpoint}
              - {
                  S3Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket,
                  S3WebEndpoint:
                    !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", websiteendpoint],
                }
            Id: S3origin
            CustomOriginConfig:
              OriginProtocolPolicy: http-only
        Enabled: "true"
        Comment: !Sub Distribution for ${DomainName}
        HttpVersion: http2
        Aliases:
          - !Ref DomainName
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
          TargetOriginId: S3origin
          Compress: True
          DefaultTTL: 604800
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: "false"
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        PriceClass: PriceClass_100
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !Ref Certificate
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
        WebACLId: !GetAtt AWSWAF.Arn
```

Comment: To be clear, you never actually retrieved the CloudFront Arn?

Comment: The solution I required didn't use it in the end. I made the question more specific to my use case deliberately to aid those who may have been approaching the problem in the same fashion I was.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct Attribute for the same but you can construct it:

```
arn:aws:cloudfront::${AWS::AccountId}:distribution/${CloudFront}
```

Comment: Our principal engineer said the same thing but I was hoping that there was an easier way. Will try this out!

Comment: Unfortunately, this produced an invalid ARN according to CloudFormation `Error reason: The ARN isn't valid. A valid ARN begins with arn: and includes other information separated by colons or slashes., field: RESOURCE_ARN, parameter: arn:aws:cloudfront::<account-id>:distribution/<cloudfront-id>`

Comment: This is weird, maybe you have issue with your sub?

Comment: `!Sub "arn:aws:cloudfront::${AWS::AccountId}:distribution/${CloudFront}"` this is literally what I have for `ResourceArn`

Comment: can you try without the quotes please?

Comment: Same error again!

Comment: Resolved it, turns out you have to add the ACL ARN to the CloudFront entry! Check my answer